# C# extention method for helper with route value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

I'm trying to make an extension method for the `ActionLink` helper with an image.

This is my extension method:

```
public static class MyHelpers
    {
        public static string ActionLinkWithImage(this HtmlHelper html, string imgSrc, string actionName)
        {
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

            string imgUrl = urlHelper.Content(imgSrc);
            TagBuilder imgTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
            imgTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", imgUrl);
            string img = imgTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

            string url = urlHelper.Action(actionName);

            TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a")
            {
                InnerHtml = img
            };

            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);

            return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
        }
    }
```

And im trying to use it like this:

```
@Html.ActionLinkWithImage("Images/del.png", "Delete", new { id = item.ItemID});
```

But my extension method does not have 'route values'. How do i implement this?

Comment: You define the Extension Method with two parameters yet you are calling it with three arguments... That doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's pointless getting snippy. Since you "obviously" noticed your error then why ask the question in the first place?

Comment: The question is/was how to implement the routing stuff. I was not talking about any compiler- or run time error. As a matter of fact, i didn't mention 'error' at all. What are you talking about?

Comment: Still no point getting aroused. My point is that it is obvious that you're missing a parameter in the declaration. For you to solve the problem you should add that parameter. Since you "obviously" are aware that you want to call the method with three arguments I don't understand why you don't add the third parameter instead of asking a silly question.

Comment: Just adding a parameter in the method doesn't do the trick without 'telling' what to do with the parameter. The question basically is what to 'tel' about that 3rd parameter.

Comment: Obviously. That's why I made it a comment and not an answer. From the question it is not certain you are aware that you need the extra parameter added to the extension method. Hence my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static string ActionLinkWithImage(this HtmlHelper html, string imgSrc, string actionName, object routeValues)
    {

    //Your code ...

    string url = urlHelper.Action(actionName, routeValues);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an object parameter to your method

```
, object routeData)
```

and pass this to the UrlHelper

```
new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(html.ViewContext.HttpContext, routeData))
```